# How can I prioritize variable names over types in Eclipse's content assist?

Tags: java, eclipse, content-assist

My Eclipse seems really bad at choosing what I want for my content assist. As you can see in this picture below, I literally have a variable defined on the previous line called "deleteTable", yet when I type "deT" and hit ctrl+space, it gives me suggestions for random classes which start with "Det" which I've never used before in my life.

[image: Bad Eclipse Content Assist]

In my `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced` options, in the first section, I only have the options "Java Proposals (Code Recommenders)" and "Template Proposals" as the two types of proposals I have enabled. And in the second section, I have cycling turned off (so when I hit ctrl+space multiple times by accident it doesn't change the suggestion drop-down).

What can I do to fix these unintuitive content assist suggestions?

Comment: I just tried `Object deleteTable = new Object();`, then typed `deT` and after pressing ctrl+space, content assist proposes `deleteTable` as the top suggestion (using default content assist settings). Could you provide an example for this behavior that can easily be reproduced on the average Eclipse install?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482707) Code Recommenders’ [Subwords completion](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#subwords-completion), which has since been fixed. Update to the newest version of Code Recommenders from the stable [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/recommenders/updates/stable/).